# lookup tables, enums and how to query them

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a table

**Images**

```
-Id
-Name
-StatusId
```

and a lookup table:

**ImagesStatus**

```
-Id
-Name
```

what would be the best practice to do a query on the images table based on StatusId?

1) Hardcode the Id:

```
db.Images.Where(x => x.StatusId == 1);
```

3) Create an enum (ImagesStatusEnum) that matches the ImagesStatus table elements and then do:

```
public enum ImagesStatusEnum
{
    Pending = 1,
    Approved = 2,
    Rejected = 3
}
int approvedStatusId = (int)ImagesStatusEnum.Approved;
db.Images.Where(x => x.StatusId == approvedStatusId).ToList();
```

3) Something else I haven't thought about?

Comment: Do you use linq to sql or EntityFramework ORM?

Comment: Then you should to use @scheien solution.

Comment: what would be the linq to sql solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EF5 and newer you can map a field on an entity to an existing enum. Right click the field in the model (type preferably int) and click convert to enum. You can then setup to use a new enum, or an existing one.

You can do your query like this:

```
    db.Images.Where(x => x.StatusId == ImagesStatusEnum.Approved).ToList();
```

I prefer the enum way since it gives a bit more readability. The cost of maintaining these enums are minimal.